# Using Ubuntu as router for CCTV

Tags: network-bridge, router

I set an system in my house and I have some issues.

I am using CCTV in my house, the DVR is located far from my internet for plug it by cord, so I toke an unused Raspberry pi 3 that I had and set him as a wifi AP by share internet connection between network cards on the Raspberry pi 3

Since the Raspberry pi 3 is tiny so no monitor connect to him and it's accessible by remote from the LAN.

On the Ubuntu, It can reach the CCTV by web, but it ask to install a Microsoft OS plugin that is not available for Linux. So I cannot reach from the Ubuntu to the web CCTV.

The Mobile app works perfectly and connecting to the CCTV. from the wifi and from the web.

I am trying to set an access from my all LAN computers on the main network to the CCTV web access.

My best guess is that the problem is blocking port 8080 on the Ubuntu. But I'm not sure.

Diagram of my network : [Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS9nZ.jpg)

Please advice how to make my LAN reply my CCTV LAN

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set up your raspberry pi routing as NAT?

Comment: Do devices in 10.0.0.* network know how to reach the 10.42.0.* network? In other words, is a route added either to the routing table of the router (10.0.0.138) or to the routing table of each of the devices telling that 10.42.0.0/24 network should be reached via gateway 10.0.0.7 and not the default gateway 10.0.0.138 ?

Comment: Also, "share internet connection" probably means NAT routing as @jad indicated above. Setup a normal, non-NAT routing on your Raspberry.

Comment: Thanks for let me know these details.

So when I run these commands 

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F


Then the DRV reply to ping, but cannot access by WEB from the 10.0.0.x network.
but every time the ubuntu reset I need to run again these commands. but again - it only allow me to get ping reply, I do need to access address by web and page is not responding.

Any more advice?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues here.

1. You wrote that you set up your Raspberry Pi with "share internet connection". Usually "share internet connection" setup means NAT routing. With NAT routing, by design you can connect from network 10.42.0.* to the network on the other side of the Raspberry (10.0.0.*), but you cannot connect the other way. You need to turn off "share internet connection" - whatever it is - and configure a regular IP packet forwarding (that means, routing) on your Raspberry. Here's a tutorial on how to do this: https://tecadmin.net/enable-ip-forwarding-linux/
2. The devices in 10.0.0.* network need to know how to reach the devices in 10.42.0.* network. Normally, they have only one default gateway - that is the router 10.0.0.138 - and they will try to connect to everything that doesn't belong to their 10.0.0.* network via that router.

So either that router, or each of the devices in 10.0.0.* network, needs to have a route added to the routing table that tells them to reach the network 10.42.0.0/24 (or 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0, whatever notation your system is using) via gateway 10.0.0.7 and not via the default gateway 10.0.0.138.

Also the devices in 10.42.0.* network must have the default gateway set to 10.42.0.1 to be able to talk back to devices from 10.0.0.* network. If you need these devices (and Raspberry itself) to be able to access Internet as well, Raspberry must have the default gateway set to 10.0.0.138.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I have set now NAT on my router, Now the 10.42.0.1 reply to ping (this is the Raspberry Pi) but no ping reply from the CCTV 10.42.0.14 Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There should be **no** NAT on Raspberry. 10.42.0.14 must have default gateway set to 10.42.0.1. Raspberry must have default gateway set to 10.0.0.138 to be able to access Internet.

Comment: Thanks for let me know these details.

So when I run these commands 

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F


Then the DRV reply to ping, but cannot access by WEB from the 10.0.0.x network.
but every time the ubuntu reset I need to run again these commands. but again - it only allow me to get ping reply, I do need to access address by web and page is not responding.

Any more advice?

Comment: I don't see why iptables should be needed for anything. 1) completely remove whatever you did previously on Raspberry to "share Internet conection"; 2) just enable IP forwarding on Raspberry according to the guide I linked; 3) setup a default gateway on Raspberry to 10.0.0.138. That should be everything you need to do on Raspberry. The rest is to setup a route to 10.42.0.0 from 10.0.0.* network, either on your router or on every device.